# stuck with onclick tried google couldn't find answer

Tags: javascript, html

i need help getting this to work, tried everything google had to offer.. but still stuck. what i need it to do is load the value of (div id="availablecredits") to (div id="beta") on click. can any body help me out?

```
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('beta').value=(javascript:document.getElementById('availablecredits').value)"
```

i also tried `onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('beta').value=('#availablecredits')"`

Comment: could you also provide the related HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `value` is common for input elements like `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>`

I think what you want is to copy a content of a `<div>` element to another div. If it's the case, use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

Here is a snippet, just click on the gray area.

```css
#div-two {
  min-height: 20px;
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-one">
  Hello this is #div-one
</div>
<div id="div-two" onclick="document.getElementById('div-two').innerHTML=document.getElementById('div-one').innerHTML"></div>
```

**SNIPPET #2**

You've defined a third `<div>` which you use as trigger but you can't click it if it's not visible, because it's `height` is 0. Specify some text inside it, then it's visible and the JS part work. Take a look at the snippet.

```css
#getCredits {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="beta">0.00</div>
<div id="availablecredits">500</div>
<div id="getCredits" onclick="document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML=document.getElementById('availablecredits').innerHTML">Click here to get available credits</div>
```

**SNIPPET #3 - jQuery**

```js
$('#getCredits').click(function() {
  $("#beta").html($('#availablecredits').html());
});;
```

```css
#getCredits {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="beta">0.00</div>
<div id="availablecredits">500</div>
<div id="getCredits">Click here to get available credits</div>
```

Comment: `onclick="document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML=document.getElementById('availablecredits').innerHTML"'` i tried it in my code its doesn't seem to be working for me, what im trying to achive is similar to this code that im using now `onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('beta').value='50'"` but instead of a fixed value i would like to display the value of (div id="availablecredits")

Comment: @EcnivNoraaWorrom `value` will not work, I've described why in the first sentence of my answer. Please post your HTML so I can create a snippet matching your ID's, but probably if you take the `onclick` from my snippet and replace the ID Strings with yours, it should work.

Comment: `<div id="beta">0.00</div>

<div id="availablecredits">500</div>

<div onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML=document.getElementById('availablecredits').innerHTML">`

Comment: @EcnivNoraaWorrom I've edited my answer, take a look at **Snippet #2** and the explanation, it should work now.

Comment: i still cant get it to work is this jquery sensitive? im using `  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @EcnivNoraaWorrom I've also added a jQuery solution in **Snippet #3** , because you mentioned that you are using jQuery

Comment: its working now how do i add +1 here in stackoverflow? thanks alot. by the way i also tried using input but its not working for input

Comment: You're welcome! You can add +1 by clicking the arrow up near the points, to mark it as the solution - *"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."*

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript function, change the ids in the function call to those of the elements in question.

```
<script>
    function set_value( src,tgt ){
        document.getElementById( tgt ).innerHTML=document.getElementById( src ).innerHTML;
    }
</script>

<style>.p5{ display:block; padding:1rem; margin:1rem; border:1px solid black;}</style>


<div class='p5' id='src_div' onclick="set_value('src_div','tgt_div')">Weebles wobble but they don't fall down!</div>
<div class='p5' id='tgt_div'></div>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="set_value('src_div','tgt_div')">Or you can use a link to set the value</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to avoid writing inline event.try this:

```html
<style>
#getCredits {
  background: #CCC;
}
</style>


<div id="beta">0.00</div>
<div id="availablecredits">500</div>
<div id="getCredits">Click here to get available credits</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('getCredits').addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML=document.getElementById('availablecredits').innerHTML;
});
</script>
```

Why inline css and javascript are bad:http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 0):

The .val() method is sometimes useful:

```
var input = $("#Input").val();
```

Comment: no jquery added in op tags and it gives value not html in this case you nee `html()`.